# yaml handlers for google app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yaml

Here is the folder structure for which I want to create a yaml file for google app engine deployment. I am confused about how to go about it.

```
MainFolder
    login.php
    register.php
    IncludeFolder
       db_connect.php
    ApiFolder
       coachlist.php
       CoachListFolder
           coach1.png
           coach2.png
       exerciselist.php
```

The indentation indicates the parent folder and child files. I can change the folder structure to something more suitable for google app engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code for yaml file on windows. script cannot be mapped with a static_dir. So the php files in ApiFolder has to be assigned a url unlike the png files in CoachListFolder. If a php file is kept in a static_dir then it is downloaded and not displayed.

```
application: <Name of application>
version: 1
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /login.php
  script: /login.php

- url: /register.php
  script: /register.php

- url: /coachlist.php
  script: /ApiFolder/coachlist.php

- url: /exerciselist.php
  script: /ApiFolder/exerciselist.php

- url: /images
  static_dir: /ApiFolder/CoachListFolder
```

app.yaml should show urls for php files that a user can access. db_connect, a folder that has database connection information, should not be accessible. Hence, it is not included in the yaml file.

Note: I think, when using linux systems, forward slash is not used before script and static_dir.